# Traverse a dictionary and do the same thing, how to optimize?

Tags: python, for-loop, listdir

I have a file dictionary for which structure looks like as follow

```
+-- folder1
| +-- folder2
    | +--A.py
    | +--A.txt
| +-- folder3 
    | +--folder4
        | +--B.py
        | +--B.txt
| +-- C.py
| +-- C.txt
```

What I want to know is to find all the `.py` files in `folder1` and write its relative path connected by `_`. For example, `B.py` can be `folder1_folder3_folder4_B.py`. Here is what I do.

```
import os
file_list = os.listdir(folder1)
for file in file_list:
    if len(file.split('.')) ==1 and file.split('.')[-1]=='py': # C.py
       print(folder1 + file) 
    elif len(file.split('.')) ==1 and file.split('.')[-1]!='py':  # C.txt
       pass
    else:
       file1_list = os.listdir(file):
       for file1 in file1_list:
           if len(file1.split('.')) ==1 and file1.split('.')[-1]=='py': # A.py
               print(folder1 + file + file1) 
           elif len(file1.split('.')) ==1 and file1.split('.')[-1]!='py':  # A.txt
               pass
           else:
               file2_list = os.listdir(file1):
               for file2 in file2_list:
                   if len(file2.split('.')) ==1 and file2.split('.')[-1]=='py': # B.py
                       print(folder1 + file + file1 + file2) 
                   elif len(file2.split('.')) ==1 and file2.split('.')[-1]!='py':  # B.txt
                       pass
                   else: 
                       pass # Actually I dont know how to write
```

There are two disadvantages:

(1) I don't know when to stop the `for` loop though I can get the max depth of `folder1`

(2) The `for` loop has so many repeat operations, obviously, it can be optimized.

Someone has a good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.walk` recursively walks a directory tree. `fnmatch.fnmatch` can wildcard match file names.  `os.path.relpath` can limit complex root paths to just the path of subfolders.

Given `testdir`:

```
C:\TESTDIR
└───folder1
    │   C.py
    │   C.txt
    ├───folder2
    │       A.py
    │       A.txt
    └───folder3
        └───folder4
                B.py
                B.txt
```

and code:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def magic(root):
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk(root):
        # fixes paths that start with .
        relpath = '' if root == path else os.path.relpath(path,root)
        for file in files:
            if fnmatch(file,'*.py'):
                name = os.path.join(relpath,file)
                yield name.replace(os.path.sep,'_')

root = r'.\testdir' # A path that starts with . for testing

for name in magic(root):
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
folder1_C.py
folder1_folder2_A.py
folder1_folder3_folder4_B.py
```

You should consider what you want to happen if a filename contains an underscore, however

Answer (score 0):

You want to use recursion, which is a fancy name for a function calling itself.  Write a function that takes a folder name as an argument.  It should run os.listdir() and loop through the results, like you are doing.  When you get to a subfolder, just run the function again!

Also, check out the .endswith() function which is easier than all the splitting.  You can just ask `if file.endswith('.py')`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did as you suggest, but there is a problem. I had run successfully for `folder3`, but for `folder4`, its path become `folder1_folder4`, because we won't keep the intermediate folder. What is your suggestion?